# How to make pages progress stepwise on a popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, popup

Can someone please explain how can I go about creating the following page and what techniques should I adopt:

1. The user should be able to click on a button which should result in a popup.
2. The popup should have a static page with instructions and button to click which takes the user to the next step in the same popup.
3. At the next step the functionality should run to take input from the user and save it to the server.
4. The user should see a confirmation finally and on clicking finish, the popup should hide.

From what I understand, I should try the following:

- use javascript onclick and fadeIn function to create the popup.
- continue changing the same div using onclick and AJAX to create stepwise kind of a format and carry out the functionality.
- use XMLHTTPRequest to upload data acquired and finally use fadeOut to hide the popup.

The reason why I am thinking in these lines is because I have had very little exposure to web designing and hence would love to get some expert views on if this is the right approach and if not then what should be a better way to do it. Is there is some existing literature/method which talks about it?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Look into using jQuery+Bootstrap, both offer methods for easily creating what you are trying to do. modal(), bootstrap steps, $.post() as some keywords

Comment: Thanks Jonas, I'll go ahead and read about modal which I was unaware of. It seems like the right thing. But will it support a dynamic popup kind of setup, where I can take a response and then execute a script to record audio?

Comment: modal is just a div "hidden" at the bottom of your page (or wherever you place it). you just need to dynamically change .modal-content (or if you go with jquery ui change #dialog)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For first step
Use javascript onclick function. But before this keep your static content ready and than use jQuery UI to appear it as good Dialog Box. For example [see this](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

For second step
The user will never know that you have changed the dialog. Just you can load new dialog with new content in it. When you click button on first page, make that first dialog box is closed.

For third step
Instead of static content make the response set to dialog, here you may use Ajax/post call.

Las step
Its not compulsion to use XMLHTTPRequest. You can even submit form in jQuery post/ajax. Than you can reload the page with confirmation message send in response from server or you may use jQuery to make the confirmation message appear.